# Create A Script That Responds To A Password Prompt

Tags: linux, shell, debian, ssh, scripting

I'm writing a shell script that will respond to a prompt. For example, when I execute a file, the executed file will then prompt the user with this:

Please enter the password:

Then I want the script to automatically place something there for this prompt.

I understand "expect" is something I can use. However, I am using SSH and I do not have root on the server I am connected to and thus I cannot install "expect" there as I do not have permission.

I have two options: Either is there another way to respond to a prompt outside of expect? Or can I run a script on my local machine outside of the SSH connection and then run that script on this SSH machine?

I am trying to enter the numbers 000 to 999 (and all numbers in between) to try as the password. So I am building loops to do this( I know how to do this, I just DK how to make it respond to the prompt) , so I'm not sure if there is something outside of expect that I can do. I just want to know if there is some way to do this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to bruteforce a three-digit PIN code on a remote server. Are you sure you are allowed to do this? :-)

Comment: yes it's a wargame server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install Expect *on the server.* Write an Expect script instead of running `expect` from a shell script. Have the Expect script itself spawn the SSH client, connect to the server and then loop through the numbers.

To save yourself some effort you can record a session where you log in to the server and try some number with `autoexpect`. Save the resulting script as, e.g., `wargame.exp` then add the loop to it. See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl10.html (Expect scripts are Tcl code).